# How to quote a command between backticks when shell scripting

Tags: shell-script, bash-scripting, escaping

The command executed in the following script works:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
REM_DIR="/home/jan/rem-dir"
SSHOPTS="-C -c arcfour256 -o "\""ServerAliveInterval 15"\"
SSHUSER="jan@example.com"

CMD="ssh $SSHOPTS \"$SSHUSER\" \"find \\\"$REM_DIR/\\\" -path *lost+found -prune -o -type f -printf \\\"%P\\\\n\\\"\""
REM_FILES=`eval $CMD`
```

It basicaly executes this on the remote host:

```
find "/home/jan/rem-dir/" -path *lost+found -prune -o -type f -printf "%P\n"
```

But how should it be escaped/formatted if I want it this way:

```
REM_FILES=`ssh ...`
```

Or:

```
REM_FILES=$(ssh ...)
```

Though my current script run just fine, I would like to know how to properly escape/quote when shell scripting.

Comment: I think youll get more support for this type of question here http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That sort of question is entirely on topic on SU as well

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) in other words, don't use all those variables.

Answer (score 1):

A better way is:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
REM_DIR="/home/jan/rem-dir"
SSHOPTS=(-C -c arcfour256 -o "ServerAliveInterval 15")
SSHUSER="jan@example.com"

REM_FILES=`ssh "${SSHOPTS[@]}" "$SSHUSER" "find \"$REM_DIR/\" -path \"*lost+found\" -prune -o -type f -printf \"%P\\n\""`
```

The main problem was with $SSHOPTS, the trick is to put each argument in a separate element of an array.

@Dennis thanks for the useful link.